# Are there any journals for physics that are similar to Crux Mathematicorum?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, popular-science

Basically, I'm looking for a physics journal that contains what Crux Mathematicorum does, which is basically a "problem solving journal" specific for the secondary and undergraduate levels. Preferably a journal that remains active to this day.

Comment: It used to be that Quantum Magazine/Kvant filled this role. These days I think the best option is the American Journal of Physics.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I'm aware, there is no such journal. However, I believe this is primarily because the majority of solvable problems have already been tabulated in books. If you are looking for such a tabulation of problems which are completable by hand and their solutions, I would suggest looking at the book series by Lim Yung-Kuo.